# Вопрос по СSS, картинки

Tags: html, css, chat

такой вопрос когда я сжимаю браузер по горизонтали то одна картинка прикрывает другую, а я хочу что бы она останавливалась в определенном месте.
                        Как сделать?
  скрины - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ylM6.jpg

```
 <div id="content"><?php include("chatGetMsg.php"); ?></div>
 <div class="box">   
    <div id="textarea"><textarea id="text" name='message' maxlength="200"></textarea></div>
    <div id="send"><button id="button" >send</button></div>  
</div>
<div class="Chan"></div>
<div class="Chan2"></div>
<div class="Anihome"></div>
```

css

```
    .Chan{
    background-image: url(c.png);
    width: 1030px;
    height: 960px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    left:0%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.Chan2{
     background-image: url(chan2.jpg);
    width: 796px;
    height: 983px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    right:0%;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

как я понял ты просто хочешь чтобы картинки остались на месте просто уменьшились если да то надо width дать не в пикселях а в %-ах

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?